# Generating SSL Certs for Customer Domains and integrating with Python Flask

Tags: python, nginx, ssl, flask, lets-encrypt

So, here is the problem I ran into, I am trying to build a very small-scale MVP app that I will be releasing soon. I have been able to figure out everything from deploying the flask application with Dokku (I'll upgrade to something better later) and have been able to get most things working on the app including S3 uploading, stripe integration, etc. Here is the one thing I am stuck on, how do I generate SSL certs on the fly for customers and then link everything back to the Python app? Here are my thoughts:

I can use a simple script and connect to the Letsencrypt API to generate and request certs once domains are pointed to my server(s). The problem I am running into is that once the domain is pointed, how do I know? Dokku doesn't connect all incoming requests to my container and therefore Flask wouldn't be able to detect it unless I manually connect it with the `dokku domains:add` command?

Is there a better way to go about this? I know of SSL for SaaS by Cloudflare but it seems to only be for their Enterprise customers and I need a robust solution like this that I don't mind building out but just need a few pointers (unless there is already a solution that is out there for free - no need to reinvent the wheel, eh?). Another thing, in the future I do plan to have my database running separately and load balancers pointing to multiple different instances of my app (won't be a major issue as the DB is still central, but just worried about the IP portion of it). To recap though:

Client Domain (example.io) -> dns1.example.com -> Lets Encrypt SSL Cert -> Dokku Container -> My App

Please let me know if I need to re-explain anything, thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to link SSL certificate with your flask app? Should it not handle by your load balancer?

Comment: @sonus21 until just now I hadn't thought of that. If that were to be the case, is there a way to have load balancers manage this? A platform or piece of software that does this for hundreds maybe thousands of customers? And how do the load balancers communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the easier way will be using Nginx container in front of python app. Because of you can just re-read Nginx config without restarting server.

I didn't work with Dokku, so try to explain how to create infrastructure simply with docker.

1. You have global IP (for example `1.1.1.1`) on your router that forwarding `80` and `443` port to internal server IP ( let it be `192.168.1.100`). global `80` to local `8080` and global `443` to local `8443`.
2. You have Nginx container that listening `192.168.1.100:8080` and `192.168.1.100:8443` and proxying all requests from `8443` to `127.0.0.1:8888` by HTTP protocol
3. You have application container that listening `127.0.0.1:8888` and accessible only from local server

Workflow will be:

1. Customer register DNS A record: `customer.domain.com A 1.1.1.1` and pointing it to your server
2. Customer adds domain to your DB using some control web page (depends on your service)
3. New record in DB starts worker container by some trigger
4. Worker container starts to check is domain exists by using some `nslookup` tool
5. If domain registered, worker starts let's encrypt script and issues new certificate (by adding `.well-known/acme-challenge` file to Nginx html folder)
6. if certificate is successfully issued, worker adds new config file into Nginx container (the better way will be mount config directory from docker host) and [reload](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/runtime-control/) Nginx configuration
7. Profit

If you need to use your own DNS server, You must to do it controllable programmatically using some API to be able add DNS A records by worker. (Good news! in this case you can use Let's Encrypt's DNS challenge by adding acme-challenge code as DNS TXT (or maybe CNAME?) record instead of Nginx `.well-known` directory)

Actually realization is deeply depends on infrastructure that you have. And that is really big task and depends on many details. So it hard to answer better without knowing it.

Answer (score -1):

Your solutions is a wildcard certificate, or use app prefixing.

So I'm not sure why you need a cert per customer, but let's say you are going to do

`customer1.myapp.com` -> routes to customer1 backend. For whatever reason.

Let's Encrypt lets you register *.myapp.com and therefore you can use subdomains for each customer.

The alternative is a customer prefix.

Say your app URL looks like `www.myapp.com/api/v1/somecomand`

you could use `www.myapp.com/api/v1/customerID/somecommand` and then allow your load balancer to route based on the prefix and use a rewrite rule to remove the customerID back to the original URL.

This is more complicated, and it is load balancer dependent but so is the first solution.

All this being said, both solutions would most likely require a separate instance of your application per customer, which is a heavy solution, but fine if that's what you want and are using lightweight containers or deploying multiple instances per server.

Anyway, a lot more information would be needed to give a solid solution.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Unfortunately, this isn't what I was looking for. See, I know about the wildcard certs and that is an easy solution because certbot will generate wildcard certs for my domain and easily link to the container which isn't the problem. The problem is when a customer want's a custom domain like "customer1.com", and that is where I am stumped on how to manage the different certs, generate, and work with them, etc.

Comment: To do what you want to do, you’d have to have control of the customer’s name server or access to their dns records or at the minimum have the customer make an A record point to your server or a CNAME record. 

Once you have that, it would be your proxy server that would handle the SSL certs. 

You can automate all that, but it sounds like a lot for an MVP. 

It seems far to complex for an MVP.

Comment: Yup, the customer would point their domain, we know of that, that's the easy part. The proxy servers could do that / the load balancers. As for complexity, we would like to be prepared to do something like that when the time comes, plus it is sort of integral to our product. Is there a tool or service you know of that does this or handles this sort of task?

Comment: Any web server could handle it. 

Nginx is my go to, you’d point the customers domain to your load balancer, Nginx, then spin up a new instance of your app for that customer. And tell Nginx all traffic coming from that url get routed to that instance